# How can I find out how to trace where Mobile Deposits to my checking account came from?

Tags: banking, checking-account

There have been several checks deposited into my checking account over the course of the year. The checks are not payable to me and the checking account is in my name.  The back of the checks are not endorsed and they are all mobile deposits. How can I find out how to trace where they came from?

Comment: Can you see images of the front of the check?  Does it have the payer's address on it?

Comment: Yes. But they are all different.

Comment: (You are right to be worried!)  Did you ask the bank?

Comment: are they all payable to the same person or to random people?

Comment: _is it enough to cash it out and move to South America?_

Comment: By "mobile deposit", do you mean a cheque deposit using a mobile phone, where photos of the front and back of the cheque are submitted to deposit the cheque? What did your bank say about why they (the bank) accepted the deposit to your account when they seem to be for someone else?

Comment: At lawerence - yes

Comment: Assuming (because you didn't mention it) nobody's been in touch asking you to "forward" or payback the money, I think it less likely that this is a scam than some kind of mistake. How long have you had this account? If you opened it not too long before the first check was deposited, it's _just about conceivable_ that the account number was reused and the cheques were meant for the previous owner.

Answer (score 3):

You have to request your bank for more details.

If you have reason to believe these are not your deposits, please report it to Bank immediately in writing.